# How to change cell properties on worksheet to avoid XLOOKUP function error 1004?

Tags: excel, vba, function, xlookup

I have designed a VBA dashboard which saves data in a listbox on the form and also in a table on the worksheet.

There are a couple XLOOKUP and Index-Match functions which do work separately for their own argument, but as I do other activities on the dashboard i get the error : "Runtime error 1004: Unable to get the XLOOKUP property of the worksheetfunction class"

Foe example: In the following code, the combo box argument "combo_remove_concrete_Change" works properly and gives me the value in the text box "Me.txt_gwp_rmix" , but the double click function does not work and gives the XLOOKUP error for this arqument

```
 Private Sub Combo_data_rmix_Change()

    Dim rng As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Source_readymix").Activate
        Set rng = Range("A2:B40")

        Me.txt_gwp_rmix.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Combo_data_rmix.Text, Range("A2:A40"), Range("B2:B40"))
        
    End With

End Sub

'''''''''''''''''' DbClick on List Box concrete'''''''''''''''


Private Sub ListBox_concrete_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)


txt_ckitid.Text = ListBox_Concrete.Column(0)
            
            If txt_ckitid.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(0) Then
               txt_ckitid.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(0)
               Combo_type_ckit.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(1)
               Txt_vol_rmix.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(2)
               Combo_data_rmix.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(3)
               txt_gwp_rmix.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(4)
               Combo_data_cmaterial.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(5)
               Combo_data_cclass.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(6)
               Txt_vol_cclass.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(7)
               txt_gwp_volcclass.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(8)
               Combo_data_cement_text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(9)
               txt_gwp_cementmix.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(10)
               Txt_cement.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(11)
               Txt_clinker.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(12)
               Txt_gypsum.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(13)
               Txt_aggregates.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(14)
               Txt_water.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(15)
               Txt_flyash.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(16)
               Txt_limequick.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(17)
               Txt_limehydrate.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(18)
               Txt_limestone.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(19)
               Txt_pozzolan.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(20)
               Txt_GGBS.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(21)
               Txt_admixtures.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(22)
               txt_volcmix.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(23)
               txt_gwp_design.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(24)
               txt_ctransport.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(25)
               txt_cpump.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(26)
               txt_cprecast.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(27)
               txt_gwp_ctotal.Text = Me.ListBox_Concrete.Column(28)


        End If
        
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''Remove combo'''''''''''''''

Private Sub combo_remove_concrete_Change()

Dim x As Long

Dim y As Long

x = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For y = 8 To x
        
            If Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 1).Value = Combo_remove_concrete.Text Then
               txt_ckitid.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 1).Value
               Combo_type_ckit.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 2).Value
               Txt_vol_rmix.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 3).Value
               Combo_data_rmix.Value = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 4).Value
               txt_gwp_rmix.Value = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 5).Value
               Combo_data_cmaterial.Value = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 6).Value
               Combo_data_cclass.Value = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 7).Value
               Txt_vol_cclass.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 8).Value
               txt_gwp_volcclass.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 9).Value
               Combo_data_cement.Value = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 10).Value
               txt_gwp_cementmix.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 11).Value
               Txt_cement.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 12).Value
               Txt_clinker.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 13).Value
               Txt_gypsum.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 14).Value
               Txt_aggregates.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 15).Value
               Txt_water.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 16).Value
               Txt_flyash.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 17).Value
               Txt_limequick.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 18).Value
               Txt_limehydrate.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 19).Value
               Txt_limestone.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 20).Value
               Txt_pozzolan.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 21).Value
               Txt_GGBS.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 22).Value
               Txt_admixtures.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 23).Value
               txt_volcmix.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 24).Value
               txt_gwp_design.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 25).Value
               txt_ctransport.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 26).Value
               txt_cpump.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 27).Value
               txt_cprecast.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 28).Value
               txt_gwp_ctotal.Text = Sheets("concrete_inventory").Cells(y, 29).Value
               
            End If
            
        Next y
        
        Combo_remove_concrete.List = Sheets("concrete_Inventory").Range("A8:A200").Value
        Combo_update_concrete.List = Sheets("concrete_Inventory").Range("A8:A200").Value

End Sub
```

I read in the internet that the problem could be the difference in the properties Text od Value. On the worksheet i played and tested the cells with text and number properties but nothing works.

any idea?

Comment: Sorry i couldnt tidy up my post and put the code in one piece. I also checked all other similar posts but they dont solve my problem.

Comment: ListBox_Concrete_DblClick doesn't contain XLookup. But it changes Combo_data_remix and I guess that Combo_data_remix_Change causes the error.
1. Try calling `MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup( ...` in the Immediate Window (press Ctr-G) and see what the message box shows. Try using other arguments. 2. Are you using an old version of Excel? Check in the Object Browser (press F2). Search for `XLookkup` and see if it lists anything.

Comment: Alternatively, try `VLookup(Combo_data_rmix.Text, Range("A2:B40", 2)`.